# Can you filter wp_dropdown_categories with terms meta?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Hi I have a custom taxonomy with a term meta flag called 'is_live' set up and I want to exclude all the terms where this flag is false when I call  **wp_dropdown_categories**.

I've checked the codex but cant see anything relating to terms meta.

Anyone have any ideas or tried this before?

Comment: You can do it with a filter on [`list_terms_exclusions`](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/hiding-default-category). Example on that link, just adjust the ID to represent the applicable ID in place of the default category code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way, hence you'll have to hack it. `wp_list_categories` calls `get_terms` internally. There's a filter `terms_clauses` which will allow you to modify the `WHERE` conditions for getting the terms. Here's how you can use it:

```
<?php
    add_filter('terms_clauses', 'term_filter', '', 1);

    function term_filter($pieces){

        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($pieces);
        //echo "</pre>";

        //You can change the entire SQL by examining the pieces array
        $pieces['where'] .= '<SQL to get the term meta>'; 

        return $pieces;
    }

    //Here's how $pieces looks like:
    Array
    (
        [fields] => t.*, tt.*
        [join] => INNER JOIN wp313_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
        [where] => tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND tt.count > 0
        [orderby] => ORDER BY t.term_id
        [order] => ASC
        [limits] => 
    )
?>
```

Append your `WHERE` condition to the default `WHERE` condition. I'm not very good with SQL (honestly, I couldn't find where term meta is stored!) hence didn't write the query. For more reference you can check the file `taxonomy.php` (line. no. 1311) and these 2 posts: [Link 1](http://www.wpmods.com/adding-metadata-taxonomy-terms/), [Link 2](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-term-or-taxonomy-meta-data).

Hope it helps!